# Add n zeros to the end of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add n zeros to an array.

When your array is x, and you want to add 3 zeros at the and of an array without creating 2 arrays:

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 7.0, 9.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 10.0])
```

I thought this command would be helpful:

```
x = [x, np.zeros(N)]
```

But I recieved 2 arrays instead of 1 big array:

```
[array([  1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   7.,   9.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   4.,  10.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])]
```

So I want to create this type of array:

```
[array([  1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   7.,   9.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   4.,  10., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])]
```

Can anyone help me with this rather simple question?

Comment: Try `np.concatenate([x, np.zeros(3)])`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), which pads default 0 to both ends of the array while in *constant* mode, specify the *pad_width = (0, N)* will pad N zeros to the right and nothing to the left:

```
N = 4
np.pad(x, (0, N), 'constant')
#array([  1.,   2.,   1.,   2.,   7.,   9.,   1.,   1.,   3.,   4.,  10.,
#         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

Comment: Currently, (I don't know if it was different in previous versions of numpy/python) the result you put would still pad both sides. Not sure why.