# How to add zeros to an shape of (x,6) np.ndarray and transform to (x,10) np.ndarray

Tags: python, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I have a prediction for x_test which has (x,8) as shape, currently I want to fill in 12 zeros to make the shape as (x,20).

Sample example:

```
[[0.10509943, 0.10455629, 0.12834423, 0.11941818, 0.18575186,
        0.09807488],
       [0.10077468, 0.10279433, 0.11094123, 0.13126894, 0.17131188,
        0.15274959],
       [0.18001982, 0.12355641, 0.12962402, 0.08898308, 0.13519354,
        0.10686492],
  
       [0.23227005, 0.12867459, 0.09090935, 0.10579092, 0.11778245,
        0.10694417],
       [0.08339332, 0.10951406, 0.08742057, 0.11066605, 0.15075919,
        0.21791006],
       [0.10345669, 0.11221684, 0.13799778, 0.13666848, 0.15356763,
        0.10952609]]
```

Each row has 6 probabilities for each class, now I want to make it 10 probabilities by adding 4 zeros after the existing probabilities

```
Output example: [0.10509943, 0.10455629, 0.12834423, 0.11941818, 0.18575186,0.09807488,0,0,0,0]
```

Please help if anyone knows
Thanks

Solution: Pad from [Add n zeros to the end of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422000/add-n-zeros-to-the-end-of-an-array)

Comment: @Rivers Yes padding works!!!

Comment: `np.pad(x_test, (0, 12))`

Comment: @not_speshal It works but not exactly I am looking for, additional 12 rows filled with all zeros also got generated
Before padding:(1246, 8)
After Padding: (1258, 20)
Should be (1246,20) instead

Comment: Try `np.pad(x_test, [(0,0),(0,3)])`

Comment: @not_speshal Awesome can you explain what this step is doing thanks!

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html). If that doesn't answer your question, search for other examples. SO is not meant to replace tutorials.